# Force Sonata to rebuild thumbs

Tags: php, symfony, thumbnails, sonata

I'm using Sonata ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/index.html ) in a project, and I have 50GB of thumbs at a resolution that I don't want anymore. I modified the resolution in the config file, but the thumbs still have the old resolution/size.

How can I force Sonata to rebuild all my thumbs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
php app/console sonata:media:sync-thumbnails sonata.media.provider.image default
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Sonata Media Bundle integrates LiipImagineBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/extra.html#liip-imagine-bundle-integration) to create image thumbnails. If so, [it creates the thumbs and saves in cache (actually, is a directory) on first request](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#basic-usage). So you have to clear the images cache, and LiipImagineBundle will rebuild them on the next request for each image.

To clear the LiipImagineBundle images cache, you can use the console command `liip:imagine:cache:remove`. Its [documentation](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Command/RemoveCacheCommand.php) says:

> The `liip:imagine:cache:remove` command removes cache by specified
>   parameters.
>
> Paths should be separated by spaces:
>   `php app/console liip:imagine:cache:remove path1 path2`
>   All cache for a given `paths` will be lost.
>
> If you use `--filters` parameter:
>   `php app/console liip:imagine:cache:remove --filters=thumb1 --filters=thumb2`
>   All cache for a given filters will be lost.
>
> You can combine these parameters:
>   `php app/console liip:imagine:cache:remove path1 path2 --filters=thumb1 --filters=thumb2`
>
> `php app/console liip:imagine:cache:remove`
>   Cache for all paths and filters will be lost when executing this command without parameters.

So, to clear all cached images you should use: `php app/console liip:imagine:cache:remove`